# Why we use process.env in nestJs application to use the variables in .env file?

Tags: process, nestjs, backend, node-modules, .env

can anyone explain why we use the `process.env` to access the variables in the `.env` files in a nestJs application? I am unable to identify where the `keyword` process is mentioned in the whole application. If it is the standard procedure I am curious to know the reason behind it.

For example :

In `main.ts` I have the below reference :

```
.
.
.
  const domainName = process.env.FRONTEND_DOMAIN;
.
.
.
```

In the `.env` file I have the variable below :

```
.
.
.
FRONTEND_DOMAIN = http://localhost:4200
```

**Problem**

The problem is I am unable to find the `process` keyword anywhere in the application even in the `package.json` file it is not imported from any packages but it is available in the `package.lock.json`.If anyone has an idea about how it works Kindly share it with me.Thanks in advance.

package.lock.json :

```
.
.
.
.
  "process": {
      "version": "0.11.10",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/process/-/process-0.11.10.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-cdGef/drWFoydD1JsMzuFf8100nZl+GT+yacc2bEced5f9Rjk4z+WtFUTBu9PhOi9j/jfmBPu0mMEY4wIdAF8A=="
    },

.
.
.
.
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#process?

Comment: It is  done for security reasons. The .env file stores sensitive data like passwords API keys etc. If you were to post your code on GitHub it would be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a nestjs stuff, it's all about nodejs & its ecosystem.

When we use some tool to load our env vars from some .env file (`dotenv` package is used by `@nestjs/config` under the hodd), it populates the `process.env` object. If your environment does not have any .env file, it won't populate anything, of course. But it also won't crash the app because this is often what we need, unless you have some validation step against those env. vars.

We usually want to use the .env file for development locally. But in production we usually inject those env. vars directly into the shell instead (eg: using `export MY_ENV='123'`)